# Displaying a user profile page PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, user-profile

I'm currently in the process of making a social network. I'm am displaying all registered users with the following code. 
Is there a better way of doing this?

```
<?php 
$query = $db->query("SELECT * from members");

while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 membersGrid">';
    echo '<div class="profileThumb">';
    echo  '<img width="130" height="130" src="'.$r['profile_pic'].'"/><br>';
    echo $r['username'], '<br>';
    echo  $r['country'], '<br>';
    echo '<a class="viewProfile" href="profile.php"><button>View Profile</button></a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

}
  ?>
```

I'm trying to create a link to the individual profile pages for each users. Currently each link is within the above while loop, however, I'm a little uncertain of how to link to the relevant profile page. I'm guessing I have to append a variable to the URL.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    echo '<a class="viewProfile" href="profile.php"><button>View Profile</button></a>';
```

Comment: In your href=profile.php add member id as parameter i.e profile.php?memberid=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend on how your profile.php page is handling the GET variable that determines the profile of the person you are showing.  Let's say that the variable is called `id` and that you have a row in your *members* table also called `id` (which acts as the unique key), then your anchor tag would look like:

```
echo '<a class="viewProfile" href="profile.php?id=' . $r['id']. '"><button>View Profile</button></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

First retrieve the **user_id** of the user from the database as you are doing with the query. Then give this id to the profile link as:

```
echo '<a href="profile.php?userid=' . $user_id . '>Linkname</a>';
```

Then in **profile.php** get this variable through:

```
$id = $_GET['userid'];
```

This way you can show the relevant user's profile in the profile.php.

Hope you might get the idea to work on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are producing a list of links to user profiles then there are a couple of different options:

You can either append a `$_GET` variable to the end of your link as previously mentioned by Lloyd

```
echo '<a href="profile.php?if=' . $r['id'] . '">';
```

or you can send a `$_POST` variable; the easiest way to do this would be to create a list of forms:

```
<?php 
$query = $db->query("SELECT * from members");
while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 membersGrid">';
    echo '<div class="profileThumb">';
    echo '<img width="130" height="130" src="'.$r['profile_pic'].'"/><br>';
    echo $r['username'], '<br>';
    echo $r['country'], '<br>';
    echo '<form action="profile.php" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $r['id'] . '" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="View Profile" />';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Sorry if I've misread your question, hope this helps.