# Individual profile page with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of profiles, and i need to make the user able to select the individual profile in a link.

I found this question and tried to follow it, but it doesnt quite work as i hoped it would: [Displaying a user profile page PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944425/displaying-a-user-profile-page-php)

The file to display all profiles on the page looks like this:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<a class="viewProfile" href="user.php?id=' . $r['UID']. '"><button>View Profile</button></a>';
}
```

But when i click the link the UID doesn't get posted in the URL, and it just looks like this: `domain/user.php?id=`

Update: With help from you guys i got the UID posted into the URL. Thanks!
And as jothi stated $id=$_GET['id'];

Comment: post value of `print_r($rows);`

Comment: probably you are looking for `$row['UID']`, as `$r` is not defined anywhere...

Comment: Yep. That did the trick :) Thanks! Now i just need to figure out how to the get values from the user with that UID..

Comment: use $row['UID'] insted of  $r['UID']

Comment: $_GET['id'] to get the value

Comment: Awesome. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `$r['UID']` is not defined. You are enumerating some `$row`, so I assume that you mean `$row['UID']`.

If it doesn't work, please, post the result of this line, just before you `foreach ($rows as $row)`

`echo print_r($rows);`